# How to make Banshee buffer my stream?

Tags: sound, banshee, streaming

I've got a HTTP stream installed on our server with mpd which streams OGG over HTTP.

If I connect with Banshee to this station the buffer is always at 0.0% and infrequently a little bit of the music gets skipped. (like 1/10th of a second)

However, when the song switches, there's a lot more skipping going on or Banshee even loses the stream.

Here's an image of the buffering in Banshee:

[image: Buffering: 0.0%]

If I use different streams (I've only tried it with M3U over HTTP streams.), the buffer fills up correctly.

Who is responsible that Banshee doesn't buffer my stream and how could I make it do this?

Comment: I have the same problem with an IceCast2 server.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards